# Secret code BroadCast receiver not working at all

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am in the process of developing an application (mainly for private use), that I want to implement a secret code system in.

I have setup the following broadcast receiver, however when I enter `*#*#887755#*#*` it doesn't launch the receiver.

Why is this? Please could anyone tell me what the issue is?

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.liamwli.spyware.usertrack"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ProcessSMS"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityConfig"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.liamwli.spyware.usertrack.ACTIVITYCONFIG" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".CodeReceive" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />

                <data
                    android:host="887755"
                    android:scheme="android_secret_code" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`CodeReceive.java`:

```
package com.liamwli.spyware.usertrack;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

class CodeReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent i = new Intent(arg0, ActivityConfig.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        arg0.startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

I do not receive *any* logcat output, and I have tried adding `android:exported="true"` to the receiver, however it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that this is due to changes in Android 3.1+

Broadcast Receivers will now not work until the app is launched on Android 3.1+, as such this app won't work.

The way to bypass this is to install it as a system application, or allow the user to launch it manually, and then hide the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try using full package name

```
<receiver android:name="com.something.something.CodeReceive" >
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference :(

Comment: Your code works fine on my phone. Typing *#*#887755#*# in dialer displays a Toast.

Comment: Ok then, *strange*. Doesn't work for me. What Android version are you running?

Comment: Confirmed working on device running 2.3.7, and emulator running 4.2